# python source paths in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

How do I set the source paths in the environment so that the pylinter sees the import from one python module to another in adjacent folders.

Each of the following imports the next module.

```
src/tests/test_mymodule1.py
src/modules/mymodule1.py
src/utils/myutil1.py
src/packages/someopensource/opensourceproj.py
```

Setting the env PYTHONPATH did not do the job. And besides we are told that "real pythoners" should NOT set the `pythonpath` for anything but for the python engine ( 2.7 or 3.6...)!

Setting it in code (with sys.path.remove and sys.path.append) allows it to run, but the linter shows `cannot import` errors.

Comment: I made a class that sets up my system path search, removes what is wrong and puts on what is correct using sys.path.append and sys.path.remove. BUT THAT DOES NOT work for the linter!!!  So I still see in the code editor (atom.io or vs-code) import not found.  

So there must be some other way. I find it hard to believe there is none. 
Or maybe I somehow have to be in the project root directory and somehow run my python code from there? (But then the tests have to be in the root!  This doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file named `.env` in the root directory
2. Add an environment variable for `PYTHONPATH` and set the path to what you need so pylint and other python programs can locate your files

   PYTHONPATH=src
3. Restart vs code.